# HoMM 3 Horn of the Abyss

Tags: mods, heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

Installed the Horn of the Abyss expansion pack, can't figure out the setting to make it properly full screen (see the inside game window you interact with?, I want to make that full screen and not bordered, the way the base game is).[image]

See the attached picture, hopefully my explanation is understandable. I'd rather have pixelly stretched out but big text and pictures than strain my old eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Install the HD mod([link](https://sites.google.com/site/heroes3hd/)) as well and launch HotA via the HD launcher.

If you can't get a good screen size even with the HD mod, try reducing the resolution. Especially the UI has trouble scaling to higher resolutions, so I usually choose only 1280x720 as my resolution for H3.

Comment: Great answer, but could you also explain where one can get the HD mod?

Comment: @mmKALLL I added a link to the answer.